# How do I handle an unpredicted alert in TruClient?

Tags: testing, functional-testing, loadrunner, truclient

How do I handle an unpredicted alert in TruClient?

My application throws an alert box sometimes notifying about system related stuff. I cannot predict when it will appear.

I do not want to add many **`Press OK in alert dialog`** all over the script.

Is there a more elegant solution?
Can I disable those alerts at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable alerts by overriding the browser implementation with an empty implementation of your own but a more elegant solution will be to use TruClient Event Handler for dialog.

See below links for more details

- http://community.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/A-closer-look-at-TruClient-Event-Handlers/ba-p/6832045#.VtWY7vl969J
  http://tchelp.saas.hpe.com/en/Latest/Content/TruClient/_tc_c_global_event_handlers.htm

Good luck

Comment: Ill try it.  Thank you